# Find which rows of a dataframe exist in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I want to perform a lookup using df1 against df2 to see if the column combination for each row in df1 exist in df2 and return a boolean. Is that possible? Thanks!

df1:

```
**First**     **Last**
Bob          Anza
Jim          Roberts
Tom          Phillips
```

df2:

```
**First**     **Last**
Bob          Phillips
Jim          Roberts
Tom          Anza
```

Return:

df3:

```
**First**     **Last**  **Match**
Bob          Anza          False
Jim          Roberts       True
Tom          Phillips      False
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it's a coincidence that in your sample data the row positions of the corresponding equal rows match.

You can construct the `'Match'` column via:

```
df1['Match'] = df1.index.isin(df1.reset_index().merge(df2)['index'])
```

Per default [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) uses the intersection of the column labels to merge on, so the line above is equivalent to:

```
df1['Match'] = df1.index.isin(df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on=['First', 'Last'])['index'])
```

In similar problems where you only want to compare "partial rows" for equality, provide the `on`, `left_on` or `right_on` arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['First'])
df3['match'] = df3['Last_x']==df3['Last_y']
print(df3)

  First    Last_x    Last_y  match
0   Bob      Anza  Phillips  False
1   Jim   Roberts   Roberts   True
2   Tom  Phillips      Anza  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df3 = df1.copy()
df3['**Match**'] = (df1 == df2).all(axis=1)
print(df3)
```

output:

```
  **First**  **Last**  **Match**
0       Bob      Anza      False
1       Jim   Roberts       True
2       Tom  Phillips      False
```

Note that this also checks if the values in the first column of `df1` and `df2` are equal.